# Is it possible to paste features into QGIS from another application?

Tags: qgis

One of the coolest features in my QGIS workflow is the ability to copy features (select and copy) and then paste the results into, say, Excel or Openoffice - you get your attributes table plus a WKT column that describes the geometry:

```
wkt_geom               id    name
POINT(250000 9012000)  1     Home
```

(You can then parse this directly in Excel using something like `=MID(A2, 7, 6)` to get the X value of the point).

What would be even better is to be able to edit that table in the external app, copy it again, and paste it back into QGIS (with the relevant layer in edit mode). However, I've tried that without success - QGIS remembers its set of copied features from the previous operation, ignoring the system clipboard (which I've confirmed has the right table stored).

Any clever ways to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently this is not supported, and I'm not sure of anyway you could hack it in from the outside.

Seems it is planned just not implemented yet https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsclipboard.cpp#L146

```
QgsFeatureList QgsClipboard::copyOf()
{
  QgsDebugMsg( "returning clipboard." );

  //TODO: Slurp from the system clipboard as well.

  return mFeatureClipboard;
}
```

I suspect it would be pretty easy to add if you have the ability to do it yourself, or pay, or know someone who can do it for you.

Comment: This would be a nice 'standard' feature.

Comment: Definitely would make a good addition to features. @Nathan-W - *is* there a way to contribute/pay for specific features in QGIS?

Comment: This is partly implemented in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/4904c06945b5697e67b3ac32fb048b4e556002ff but it only handles WKT at the moment.